# Predict multi class in svm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I have user review dataset like

```
review-1, 0,1,1,0,0
```

`review-1` is user review and `0,1,1,0,0` is review categories. one review can have multiple categories. I want to predict categories to reviews. so I implement the code that

```
transformer = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True, stop_words=stop, max_features=500)
X = transformer.fit_transform(df.Review)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, df.iloc[:, 1:6],
                                                test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

SVM = svm.SVC()
SVM.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I'm getting error like

```
ValueError: bad input shape (75, 5)
```

Could anyone suggest any good solution to solve this?

Comment: Please check out documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit . `SVC` does not support multilabel classification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a binary classifier (like `svm.SVC()`) to solve the multi-label classification problem using `OneVsRestClassifier`.

**Example:**

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

from sklearn.svm import SVC

cls = OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SVC(gamma ='auto'))

import numpy as np
cls.fit(np.random.rand(20,10),np.random.binomial(1,0.2,size=(20,5)))
```